# difference between php fmod function and arithmetic % operator

Tags: php

What is difference between PHP **fmod** function and **arithmetic % operator**  ?

Here its give diff output

```
 fmod(1438090136928 , 268435456)
```

and

```
1438090136928 % 268435456
```

When to use these functions?

Edit

Which one is more faster ?

Comment: `echo 5.7 % 1.3;
 echo fmod(5.7, 1.3);` See the difference? <- With this you can probably think for what the **f** stands for. (Also reading the manual always helps: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php)

Comment: ' If you want the remainder of the division of two Integers rather than Floats, use "%" ' from http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fmod.php

Answer (score 3):

As [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) says:

> Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the
>   decimal part) before processing.

But [fmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) accepts float values and return a float value also.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the differences in detail but the following information might help :-

1. The modulus can only handle numbers upto 4294967296 i.e 2^32
2. Both [`fmod`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) and `%` are native
3. You should also consider using [php math functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php), as they can handle larger numbers and comparatively faster

Thanks, hope it helps.